What comic is this where Superman was controlled by rock music?
Back in the 1980s I looked at a pile of Superman comics at a flea market. One that I remember and would like to identify involved Superman dealing with a rock band, the music of which drove the audience and Superman to compulsive behavior.
"Diga-diga" the audience chanted and were compelled to dig, and similarly "fighta-fighta" (much more dangerous of course).

This is Action Comics #398 - The Pied Piper of Steel.
The band says "Dig that rock" and the crowd does it, while chanting "dig-a-dig!"

